# Paypal API recurring payment bi-weekely

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

i want weekely or biweekly payment in paypal recurring payment

```
<input type="text" name="srt" value="" id="srt"/>
<input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1" />
</div>  <div class="input-in">    <label>Recurring Amount:</label>    
<input type="text" name="a3" id="txtName" />    
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1" /></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a reference guide in what hidden variables can be used.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HI00JQU

You are also looking at the "t3" variable to when the payment is due.

```
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1" /></div>
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="W" /></div>
```

t3 denotes weeks.
p3 denotes "every"

So every 1 week.

Comment: t3 variable repersent day,week,month,year but not bi-weekly

Comment: Yes. It represents a period. So you would change the value to p3 to "2" so that it would be "bi"-weekly or 2 weeks.

Comment: it means if i wnat to select weekely payment p3=1 and if i select bi-weekly payment p3=2

Comment: theres is different between weekely or biweekely biweekely after 2 weeks